# when ng-repeat list of folders updates wrong

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have receive listof objects with names: F1,F2,F3,F4
when I make call to server, I receive new list F1,F2,F3,F5,F4
when I apdate ng-repeat list:

```
vm.folders = data.content.items;
```

it shows next list: F1,F2,F3,F4,F4
where am I wrong? here is my html code:

```
<div  ng-repeat="folder in vm.folders track by $index" ng-init="openInput=false;">
    <div layout="row"    ng-init="folderName = vm.getIterationName(folder.metadata)" >
        <div >
        </div>
        <div >
            <span ng-click="showChildren[$index]=!showChildren[$index]" class="capitalize"  ng-dblclick="openInput = true;$event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="!openInput">{{folderName}}</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js update method:

```
 function updateIterations(data) {
        if (data.ok === true) {
            if(angular.toJson(vm.folders) != angular.toJson(data.content.items)) {

                vm.folders = data.content.items;

            }
        } else if (data.ok == false) {
            console.log ('Error:iteration request: {ok: false}');
            $interval.cancel(intervalRequests);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try with `angular.copy(data.content.items,vm.folders)` instead of `vm.folders = data.content.items;`?

Comment: `angular.toJson(vm.folders) != angular.toJson(data.content.items)` not going to work.

Comment: with angular.copy(data.content.items,vm.folders) - the same issue

Answer (score 0):

fixed!
in

```
<span ng-click="showChildren[$index]=!showChildren[$index]" class="capitalize"  ng-dblclick="openInput = true;$event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="!openInput">{{folderName}}</span>
```

instead of {{folderName}} i've used:

```
<span ng-click="showChildren[$index]=!showChildren[$index]" class="capitalize"  ng-dblclick="openInput = true;$event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="!openInput">{{vm.getIterationName(folder.metadata)}}</span>
```